# Xcode 9, Simulator 10 CPU stress

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

Running my app on the new simulator, a process called `backboardd` is causing very high CPU utilization.

I'm doing some animation via `CADisplayLink` (moving about 18 views at once), no OpenGLES running ([as was discovered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46234101/googlemaps-on-simulator-in-xcode-9-uses-over-100-of-cpu-when-moving-the-map)).

The same problem is not apparent in Xcode < 9.  Is this just another one of those issues where we sit tight -- potentially for years, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5900245/294949) -- while Apple fixes?

Comment: High CPU is very normal with simulator running.  Simulating a faster-CPU phone tends to run slower than simulating older, slower phones.

Comment: @drewster Could you explain why simulating newer iphone is slower ?

Comment: `backboardd` hosts the windowserver on iOS. If you can open a bug report with a sample application and some numbers comparing iOS 10 vs iOS 11 in the Simulator that would be very helpful. Please send me the radar # and I will take a look at it.

Comment: Same problem here. Any one found a solution to this issue?